# How do straight quotes become curved quotes when copying from a web page to a text editor?

Tags: characters

I copied some code from a web page and into my text editor.

**The double quote characters changed to this**:

```
<iframe src=“http://www.yahoo.com” style=“width:500px; height:500px;” frameborder=“0?></iframe>
```

**instead of this** (which is what I needed):

```
<iframe src="http://www.yahoo.com" style="width:500px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

**Why?**

Comment: What editor are you using?

Comment: I'm using Netbeans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some editors don't handle "smart quotes" well or forcibly convert them to "dumb quotes".

**EDIT**: I read your examples backwards - the opposite happened: you got so-called "smart" quotes from plain ones.  In some editors, that's a configurable setting.  And understand that *word processors* are very different from ordinary *text editors*.  Using Word as a text editor can do strange and damaging things to code or markup languages.

Comment: yup, change your editor :) +1

Comment: I think he's saying that it converted "dumb" quotes to "smart" quotes.  Which would imply that he's using a word processor of some nature, and not a text editor.

Comment: @wfaulk - yah, you're right.

Comment: No, I'm not using a word processor - I'm using Netbeans, which is a programming IDE.

Comment: I don't have NetBeans installed here, but a little googling found this: Tools -> Options -> Editing -> Editor Settings -> Java Editor -> Pair Character Completion.  I'm not sure if the setting can be applied to the editor generally or is language-specific.

Answer (score 1):

You need a text editor that's HTML aware e.g. [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm). Either that or something 'dumber' than the editor you're using (like Notepad) which won't attempt to 'smart-quote' your code.

Comment: Actually, any real text editor would do better than that, HTML-aware or not.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the software is trying to be helpful. If, when you type a quote, it becomes a “ character, wouldn't you want it to do the same conversion when pasting in text?